# How to stop bokeh server?

Tags: python, bokeh

I do use bokeh to plot sensor data live on the local LAN. Bokeh is started from within my python application using popen: `Popen("bokeh serve --host=localhost:5006 --host=192.168.8.100:5006", shell=True)`

I would like to close bokeh server from within the application. However, I cannot find anything in the [documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/cli.html#userguide-cli). Also `bokeh serve --help` does not give any hint how to do that.

EDIT: based on the accepted answer I came up with following solution:

```
        self.bokeh_serve = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command),
                             shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I used `self.bokeh_serve.kill()` for ending the process. Maybe `.terminate()` would be better. I will try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing bokeh and assuming that you use Python >= 3.2 or Linux, you could try to kill the process with `SIGTERM`, `SIGINT` or `SIGHUP`, using [`os.kill()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill) with [`Popen.pid`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.pid) **or even better** [`Popen.send_signal()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.send_signal). If bokeh has proper signal handlers, it will even shutdown cleanly.

However, you may be better off using the option `shell=False`, because with `shell=True`, the signal is sent to the shell instead of the actual process.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using Linux based OS then open terminal and type

```
ps -ef
```

Search for the bokeh application file running in the process and note down the PID i.e. Process ID, suppose process ID id 3366 then using command

```
kill 3366
```

kill the process.

Comment: I would do like this: 
```ps -ef | grep bokeh```

In this case, only processed id related to bokeh will be appeared in Terminal and then 
```kill -9 <process id>```.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very simple way that I use in my *Python 3.7* with *Bokeh* server programming to stop the server, with no explicit *Tornado* or *Server* imports. My OS is *Windows 7* and I use *Python 3.7* because *Python 3.8* is not compatible with *Bokeh* server

I start a *bokeh* server from outside with

```
bokeh serve --show myprogr.py
```

The content of  `myprog.py`:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button
from bokeh.layouts import column, widgetbox
import sys

def button_callback():
    sys.exit()  # Stop the server

def add_circles():
    # 10 more circles
    sample_plot.circle(x=np.random.normal(size=(10,)),
                       y=np.random.normal(size=(10,)))

bokeh_doc = curdoc()
sample_plot = figure(plot_height=400, plot_width=400) # figure frame

# Button to stop the server
button = Button(label="Stop", button_type="success")
button.on_click(button_callback)

bokeh_doc.add_root(column([sample_plot, widgetbox(button, align="center")]))
bokeh_doc.add_periodic_callback(add_circles, 1000)
bokeh_doc.title = "More and more circles with a button to stop"
```

One can see in your default web browser. It adds a new tab and shows a graph with a growing number of small circles until press `stop` and see that the party is over.