# How to properly stop a separate thread together with shutting down a bokeh server?

Tags: multithreading, windows-10, bokeh, python-3.7

I'm trying to plot a 'real time' plotting streaming some sensor data using the bokeh server. Meanwhile I want to start a separate theread to 'manipulate' the same data with some file i/o operation to the hard drive.
From multiple sources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60288147/4015990) and [here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#updating-from-threads), I was able to assmeble a script shown below. However when I run `bokeh serve --show test.py` in the command prompt, the webpage never load. And the server is just frozen. Could anyone please point out what I should do? Thank you for any help.

For simplicity, the `blocking_task` for the separate thread contains only a `time.sleep` function. The plot will show up if the last three lines are commented out (they are for the separate thread).

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button
from bokeh.layouts import column, widgetbox

import time
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
from threading import Thread
import sys

# the function to be called by the separate thread
def blocking_task():
    while True:
        if stop_threads:
            print('thread killed')
            sys.exit()
        time.sleep(0.1)

# the 'stop' button under the plotting
def button_callback():
    global stop_threads
    stop_threads = True


def update():
    data = np.random.rand()
    source.stream(dict(time=[dt.datetime.now()], data=[data]), 100)


doc = curdoc()
stop_threads = False  # a global flag used for stopping the separate thread

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(time=[], data=[]))
fig = figure(x_axis_type='datetime', plot_width=800, plot_height=400)
fig.line(x='time', y='data', source=source)

button = Button(label="Stop", button_type="success")
button.on_click(button_callback)

doc.add_root(column([fig, widgetbox(button, align="center")], sizing_mode='stretch_both'))
doc.add_periodic_callback(callback=update, period_milliseconds=100)

thread = Thread(target=blocking_task)
thread.start()
thread.join()  # I can comment out this line to show the streaming plot, but there is no way to stop the separate thread together with shutting down the server.
```

Answer (score 2):

`join()` waits for the thread to stop before continuing execution. `bokeh serve` wraps the whole script in a function that is expected to return, which never happens in your case.

Try removing just the last line and setting `daemon=True` in the `Thread` constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, after I move the `sys.exit()` to the end of `button_callback()` function, when I click the 'stop' button. The server just becomes frozen. My question is, how do I properly stop this separate thread together with shutting down the server?

Comment: I have updated the answer to include the `daemon=True` argument. Also, if you move the `sys.exit()` line to a different location, be sure to leave `break` or `return` in its place.

Answer (score 1):

I will avoid the daemon flag according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/threading.html#thread-objects):

> Daemon threads are abruptly stopped at shutdown. Their resources (such
>   as open files, database transactions, etc.) may not be released
>   properly. If you want your threads to stop gracefully, make them
>   non-daemonic and use a suitable signalling mechanism such as an Event.

I will instead check the `threading.main_thread().is_alive()` in the while loop of the child thread

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button
from bokeh.layouts import column, widgetbox

import time
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import threading
import sys


def blocking_task():
    while threading.main_thread().is_alive():
        time.sleep(0.1)
    else:
        print('exiting child thread')


def button_callback():
    sys.exit()


def update():
    data = np.random.rand()
    source.stream(dict(time=[dt.datetime.now()], data=[data]), 100)


doc = curdoc()

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(time=[], data=[]))
fig = figure(x_axis_type='datetime', plot_width=800, plot_height=400)
fig.line(x='time', y='data', source=source)

button = Button(label="Stop", button_type="success")
button.on_click(button_callback)

doc.add_root(column([fig, widgetbox(button, align="center")], sizing_mode='stretch_both'))
doc.add_periodic_callback(callback=update, period_milliseconds=100)

thread = threading.Thread(target=blocking_task)
thread.start()
```